# IPv6 ephemeral port range

Tags: linux, ipv6

In Linux, I can get and set the range of ephemeral ports through `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

I want to control the ephemeral port range for IPv6, but there seems to be no such file under `/proc/sys/net/ipv6`.

Does the setting for IPv4 apply to IPv6 connections as well?  Or is there another way to set the ephemeral port range for IPv6?

Answer (score 9):

IPv6 stack uses the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` setting.

Comment: Thanks! Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch11s03.html mentions IPv6-related entries in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/, and ip_local_port_range is one of them.